# find all records for specific month by its month number (e.g. 1 = January)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Using Rails 4.2, Ruby 2.1.7. Postgresql 9.4

I'd like to find all records for a specific month when I just have an integer as parameter.

e.g. 1 = January, 2 = February

Right now I have (start_time is my `datetime` field)

```
def self.by_month(month)
  where('extract(month from start_time) = ?', month)
end
```

The resulting SQL query is:

```
SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE (extract(month from start_time) = 1)
```

Comment: The format matters here. Try creating in `yyyy/mm/dd` format.

Comment: @Pavan the format for month? How to create `Date.new` ?

Comment: Show some sample data and the SQL query you are running. Also what is the data type of the `month` variable. That should be an integer because `extract()` returns an integer

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to create and store your records. Also, please show some example data which works OK for you, and some that does not work.

Comment: No. Try creating the `start_time` in that format and check.

Comment: `SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE (extract(month from start_time) = 1)`  works. But as I said, when I create for Feb 1st 00:00h its also in January. `1` is an integer.

Comment: @daniel Does your date format always dynamic or it is fixed always ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit the date format is a `datetime` format column.

Comment: @daniel I meant the value of `month` .

Comment: @ArupRakshit The value of month will always be an integer and should change from 1 - 12

Comment: Ok then what do you mean by `Feb 1st 00:00` ? Is this your input data? Help me to understand you, so that I can help you. I am not getting where you get stuck.

Comment: His input data is an integer which denotes the month, and he is trying to select records based on dates stored in a date_time column.

Comment: @ArupRakshit oh sorry yes this date is from a form select input field. The POST request from the log is this `["start_time", "2016-03-31 22:00:00.000000"]` for February 1st 00:00h

Comment: @daniel Please add the log in the post. Your issue is saving the data or querying the data ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit query the data

Comment: @daniel What that `POST` request is for ? from where you are passing the month value to query ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit The POST request is not relevant. Its a standard datetime POST from a form. I said that because you wanted to about `Feb 1st 00:00`. But I just want to retrieve records for a certain month with a integer as parameter

Comment: How this line *But when I create an object for 'February 1st 00:00' through the input form field its not listed in February, but in January* is relevant to your question ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes right. I deleted that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102634/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-daniel).

Answer (score 1):

A better solution may be to use a range of dates. ActiveRecord turns this into a `WHERE x BETWEEN y AND z` as extracting the month could be ambiguous if you have several years of records.

Something like this:

```
def self.by_month(int)
  int = int - 1 # convert month from 1 to 0 based
  now = DateTime.now
  if int < (now.month + 1) # now.month is 1 based
    min = now.beginning_of_year + int.months
  else
    min = now.last_year.beginning_of_year + int.months
  end

  where(start_time: [min..(min.end_of_month)])
end
```

How your exact method ends up depends on how you want to deal with month that could fall into the previous year or the next year.

In some cases it might make more sense to have your users select a month with a date input so that you can distinguish.